# Are questions concerning the modification of puzzles into new ones on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are many niches in puzzle society that consistently modify existing physical puzzles to create new ones.

For instance, in the twisty puzzling community, which I'm a rather active part of, the hexaminx:

[image: hexaminx]

is a shape-modification of the megaminx, and was originally constructed manually:

[image: megaminx]

My question primarily concerns refinement of the scope of "puzzle creation" in our site topic - does this include the methods by which one modifies existing puzzles?

Comment: Why not?​​​​​​​

Comment: @Doorknob Fair point. The distinction in my mind is that this concerns the actual physical modification of puzzles, while other puzzle creation questions might concern the logical derivation of puzzles. In other words, these are construction questions.

Comment: So...? Why does that make them off-topic?

Comment: Hrrrrrrm. I'm not entirely sure. It just... didn't come up during the definition phase of the site, so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3):

As long as they are properly scoped, yes.

Good:

> I am trying to create a puzzle similar to a Rubik's Cube but in the shape of a torus, but I can't figure out how to keep it cohesive. How do I keep it from falling apart?

Bad:

> I am trying to create a puzzle similar to a Rubik's Cube but in the shape of a torus. WAT DO